# Unknown limit switch on a commercial camera iris diaphragm

Tags: switches, camera, pinout

I am working on this spare iris of a Canon EF 24-105 mm lens for an hobby project.
[image: Text]
The iris has 8 pins:

- 4 related to a micro-stepper motor;
- 4 linked to some sort of limit switch.

The limit switch is closed (or opened) by a small plastic clip passing in the middle of the sensor; no mechanical contact occurs.

Someone knows the working principle of this limit switch and how it can be wired to make it work?

**EDIT**

I dismounted the sensor by desoldering the ribbon cable and by exposing the internal component by the plastic cover. The sensor is composed by a single piece.
[image: I have dismounted the sensor by desoldering the ribbon cable and by exposing the internal component by the plastic cover. The sensor is composed by a single piece.]
I took different angulations pictures: in the slot there is no sign of lenses or any other optical feature.
[image: I took different angulations pictures: in the slot there is no sign of lenses or any other optical feature.]

Comment: Optical or is there a magnet in the plastic?

Comment: Hall sensors are unlikely to need 4 wires, so 2 wires to an LED and 2 to a photodiode is most likely.

Comment: @Brian Drummond I took some pictures of the dismounted sensor and I cannot see any clue about optical functionalities.

Comment: @Solar Mike I cannot verify if the clip contains ferric material since the frame is ferric. I cannot verify your indication without fully dismounting the diaphragm and I am not sure I can remount it after. Sorry.

Comment: Certainly looks like an opto interrupter. Use the diode test setting on a DVM to look for a diode with a forward voltage about 1.5V on  one side (infra-red LED).

Comment: @BrianDrummond On the 2 pins on the side with a white mark there is a voltage drop of 1.069 V. Nothing measured on other pins. Even continuity. I suppose is NO side of the sensor.

Comment: @BrianDrummond you were right! I managed to make it work!

Comment: @user_1818839 Hall sensors using SPI are fairly common.